# Radio button cant be clicked/checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-deployment

i am trying to use radio buttons using asp.net which are in a container but if i select the right radio button, the left radio button becomes checked, even though i clicked the right one.

this is my code:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoSmallJars" Text="Small" runat="server" GroupName="measurementSystem" style="z-index: 1; left: 350px; top: -440px; position: absolute; height: 21px;" AutoPostBack="True"/>

<asp:RadioButton ID="rdo1" Text="Test" runat="server" GroupName="measurementSystem" style="z-index: 1; left: 450px; top: -440px; position: absolute; height: 21px;" AutoPostBack="True" />
```

any ideas?
thank you

Comment: Removing `AutoPostBack="True"` if you are not handling the `OnCheckedChanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

You  need to give each radio button a Value. If you don't they will both have the same default Value and clicking on either of them will be equivalent to clicking on the first one with the value.

e.g:

```
<asp:RadioButton Value="1" ID="rdoSmallJars" Text="Small" runat="server" GroupName="measurementSystem" style="z-index: 1; left: 350px; top: -440px; position: absolute; height: 21px;" AutoPostBack="True"/>

<asp:RadioButton Value="2" ID="rdo1" Text="Test" runat="server" GroupName="measurementSystem" style="z-index: 1; left: 450px; top: -440px; position: absolute; height: 21px;" AutoPostBack="True" />
```